# How to return boolean from .filter()

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to return a boolean indicates the evaluation of the condition in the `.filter()` as shown below in the code.

when I execute the code i got an array but i want to get true or false based on the evaluation of the following condition

```
program instanceof Program
&& program.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R
&& program.isConfigTag('Mu'))
```

**code**:

```
this._featureContr.getPrograms().filter((program) =>
      program instanceof Program
      && program.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R
      && program.isConfigTag('Mu'));
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `any` or `every`

Comment: `this._featureContr.getPrograms().every((program) =>`

Comment: @J.Pichardo would you please provide an example

Comment: is the result of `this._featureContr.getPrograms()` an array?

Comment: @ArunPJohny would you please provide an example

Comment: do you want a single true or false value or array of true and false values

Comment: @Prasanna would you please provide example for both cases..i need booth please

Answer (score 1):

JS arrays have two functions that might work for you, `every` and `some`

> The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function.
>
> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

So based on the result you want, you could do the following:

```
this._featureContr.getPrograms()
  .every((program) =>
    program instanceof Program &&
    program.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R &&
    program.isConfigTag('Mu'));
}

this._featureContr.getPrograms()
  .any((program) =>
    program instanceof Program &&
    program.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R &&
    program.isConfigTag('Mu'));
}
```

If want you want is an array of the test results, then you should use `map`

```
this._featureContr.getPrograms()
  .map((program) =>
    program instanceof Program &&
    program.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R &&
    program.isConfigTag('Mu'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter returns an array.
In your case you need to use reduce : [reduce - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/reduce-method-array-javascript)

```
this._featureContr.getPrograms().reduce(function(p,n){
     return p && (n instanceof Program
          && n.getHeader().getSpace() === ProgramSpace.C_R
          && n.isConfigTag('Mu'));
},true)
```

This starts with p as true, then it iterated and applies the condition for each (next item) n and returns to the next ireation the resut as the next p.

Comment: There are functions that work better with `predicates` like `every` or `some`

Comment: @J.Pichardo would you please tell me what is P and n?

Comment: Well, is not my answer, but,  `p` refers to the result of the previous evaluation and `n` the next item in the array